Can a non-trivial continuous function "undo" the discontinuities of another function?
Apologies for the unclear title, I have no idea if the property I'm looking for has a better name.
I'm wondering if there exists a pair of functions $f, g : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that :

$g$ is a bijection and is nowhere continuous (for an example, see this answer).
$f$ is continuous and not constant.
$f \circ g$ is continuous.


Does 1) mean that $g$ has an inverse?

@JosBergervoet Yes indeed.

But doesn't this inverse simply "undo" what the function does? And in a unique way, I'd say (there can be only one inverse). So if that is not continuous your question is answered with no...

@JosBergervoet Yes, but the inverse of $g$ isn't continuous, which violates condition 2. To be clear, when I say "undo discontinuities" I don't mean that $f \circ g$ should be the identity, only that it should be continuous.

Yes (sorry, I edited that in too late). That is my point. It will not usually be continuous so there you have your answer... (Unless you mean with "undo" something else than the inverse, I was just assuming that.)

@JosBergervoet I'm not sure I understand your line of reasoning. Indeed $g^{-1}$ isn't continuous, so it isn't a suitable candidate for $f$. But how does it follow from this that no other function $f$ can fit the bill?
Edit: sorry, I missed that part of your comment: yes, I do mean something different with "undo", I don't mean the inverse of $g$. Sorry for the misunderstanding!

I was just wondering what bill you wanted to fit, but I see now what you mean, I think!

There are many (non-constructible except by using choice!) non-identity invertible $\mathbb{Q}$-linear maps from $\mathbb{R}$ to itself which are identity only on $\mathbb{Q}$. Any of these should provide an example.

This is possible. In fact, the $g$ in the answer you linked to will work. Recall that $g$ is defined by,
$$g(x) = \begin{cases} x + 1 &, x \in \mathbb{Q}\\
x &, x \notin \mathbb{Q}\end{cases}$$
Let $f(x) = \sin(2\pi x)$. Then $f$ is periodic with period $1$, so $f \circ g(x) = \sin(2\pi x)$, which is continuous.

Here is an answer to a follow-up question the OP posted in comments: namely, whether for any such $g$ there always exists an $f$ satisfying the requirements of the question. The answer is no, as the following example demonstrates.
Let $\{E_i\}_{i \in I}$ be the collection of equivalence classes (of real numbers) under the equivalence relation $x - y \in \mathbb{Q}$. Let $\{E_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be a countably infinite collection of such equivalence classes. Let $\{q_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be an enumeration of rationals with $q_1 = 0$. Define $g$ by,
$$g(x) = \begin{cases} x + q_n &, x \in E_n\\
x &, \, \mathrm{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
Since each $E_n$ is dense, it is not hard to verify that $g$ is indeed bijective and nowhere continuous. Now assume $f$ is a continuous function s.t. $f \circ g$ is continuous. Note that, on $E_n$, $f \circ g(x) = f(x + q_n)$. By density of $E_n$ and continuity of the functions on both sides, we see that $f \circ g(x) = f(x + q_n)$ must hold for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. But this means,
$$f(0) = f(0 + q_1) = f \circ g(0) = f(0 + q_n) = f(q_n)$$
for all $n$. Thus, $f$ is constant on rationals. By continuity of $f$ and density of rationals, we conclude that $f$ must be constant.

Thanks! This is spurring a ton of questions for me (given an arbitrary $g$, will we always be able to find a corresponding $f$? what if we add constraints on $f$, for instance that it not be periodic? what if we want $g \circ f$ to be continuous instead?...). Do you know if these questions belong to a particular field, or if there are keywords which could help me find relevant papers?

@TheAmazingKitchen continuity is studied much in topology, but I have never seen something like your original question (though I don't have much experience).
For the first question, I think for the function that maps the rationals to zero and the irrationals to one, the only undoers are constant functions, so the answer is no.
I think the questions in your comment are interesting (though I am not sure periodicity is important), and I think you should post some of them. I am myself interested in finding conditions on $g$ such that undoers exist.

@Aldoggen I believe the OP asks for $g$ to be a bijection, and what you proposes is not a bijection. In any case, to deal with your example, you only need $f$ to send $0$ and $1$ to the same value, and there are plenty of continuous functions that are not constant but send $0$ and $1$ to the same number.

@TheAmazingKitchen I edited my answer to add in an example showing that your first question has a negative answer.

@TheAmazingKitchen Periodicity is not necessary. Though admittedly this example is a bit of cheating: let $g(x)=(x+1)^3$ on algebraic numbers and $g(x)=x^3$ otherwise. Then $f(x)=\sin(2 \pi x^{1/3})$ would work, and $f$ is not periodic.

@TheAmazingKitchen I’m unsure as to whether $g \circ f$ can be continuous. Likely not, but I haven’t found a proof yet. As for finding relevant papers, I don’t think there’s any modern papers addressing this specific kind of questions. Perhaps there would be some old papers, from 19th century and early 20th century, during the early development of modern real analysis? There were some efforts to construct real variable functions with exotic properties back then.
